# Symfony2 KNP Snappy IE9 give 0byte pdf & Firefox, Opera works

Tags: symfony, internet-explorer-10, wkhtmltopdf

I am using the **KNPSnappy Bundle** with the **Google Tool Wkhtml2pdf**.
That is working with the **Firefox 31** I use for the development (and Opera).
On our Company Computers is **IE9** available.

With the IE I get an error:

1. There is the Question about open or save the file.
2. If I choose save it will tell note(3) couldn't be downloaded.
3. If I click retry it will freeze the IE.

I did check that the webpage is local internet with Low security level.
Working on an Centos/Apache Server.
Did not find an error in log off Apache or Symfony or Eventlog.
Where to find and information?

The File name 'note' that comes with error in IE is not the filename that was created in Firfox.

Answer (score 0):

I did find the problem that was breaking the IE9.
The 201 as a response code was the problem just changed it to 200 and also the IE was working fine like the Firefox and the Opera did.

```
    return new Response ( 
        // use wkhtmltopdf options
        $this->get ( 'knp_snappy.pdf' )->getOutputFromHtml ( $html, array (
                    'orientation' => 'Portrait',
                    'images' => true 
            ) ), 201, array (
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
                    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="Invnr_' .$id. '.pdf"',
                    'Charset' => 'UTF-8',
                    'images' => true,
                    'print-media-type' => true 
            ) );
```